# Cheating Cyclic Quine

Tags: code-golf, quine, code-generation

### Concept

Write a program that outputs code in its programming language. That code, when executed, must output the original program.

### Rules

- Since this is a cheating quine, you can read the original source code.
- First output program must be in the same language as the original program.
- You may not output a regular quine. The two programs must be different.
- Standard loopholes apply.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer wins, however it will not be selected.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what constitutes a semi-quine.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien It outputs a program that outputs the original program

Comment: I see. The wording is quite vague.

Comment: Why wont the shortest answer be selected? Is this a Catalog?

Comment: [We already have another definition for semiquine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71473/45941). This is a cyclic quine. [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/52596/45941).

Comment: I'd call it square root of quine. (Because I like how quantum computing has the operator square root of not.)

Comment: Really, the only differences between this and the challenge I linked are that cheating quines are allowed and the chain needs to be of length 2. I'm not going to VTC this as a dupe (since my vote is a hammer), but I will put forward the proposal that this might be a dupe.

Comment: Just for the record, I'd call it a [mutual quine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2582/8478) (that challenge requires *different* languages though).

Comment: @Mego I'll give my two cents, This is not a dupe as this is Code-Golf, not Code-Challenge. The Quine Permutation Group challenge asks for a very different solution, as is obvious by Dennis's.

Comment: @ATaco The other challenge scored based on code length and chain length. With the exception of the few solutions that are infinitely extendable, most of the chain lengths were small, so the score was dominated by code length.

Comment: Since this is a cheating quine, can we choose to not follow the rules?

Comment: @Keeta No, cheating only means that you can read the source code

Answer (score 28):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 11 bytes

```bash
tr xy yx<$0
```

This prints

```bash
tr yx xy<$0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19SpFBRqVBZYaNi8P8/AA)

In turn, that prints

```bash
tr xy yx<$0
```

Comment: Not a cheat and in a common language.

Comment: I think the `tr` command is redirected to `$0` which is its own source code. So it is "cheaty".

Answer (score 21):

## [7](http://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 2 bytes

7 uses a 3-bit character set, but takes input packed into bytes (and according to meta, [languages with sub-byte character sets are counted using bytes for the file on disk](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10810/62131)). Here's an `xxd` dump of the program:

```
00000000: 4cf4                                     L.
```

When giving this file to the 7 interpreter, it will output the following program:

```
00000000: 4fa6 7f                                  O..
```

which will then in turn output the original program again.

So what's happening here? There's no source reading involved (actually, I don't think it's possible to read the source in 7), although arguably the program is cheating in another way; let me know what you think. Here's how the program works. (Note that each 7 command has two variants, some of which don't have names and can't appear in the original program. There are twelve commands total, in six pairs. I'm using bold for active commands, nonbold for passive commands, and in cases where the active command has no name, I'm giving it the same name as the corresponding passive command and relying on the bold to distinguish. In the case where both are named, e.g. `7` which is the active variant of `1`, each command gets its own name and the bold is just syntax highlighting.)

```
231723       Original program, unpacked into octal
231          Push 237 onto the stack
    23       Push 23 onto the stack
             (implicit) append a copy of the top of stack to the program
      2      Duplicate top of stack (currently 23)
       3     Output top of stack, pop second stack element
```

At this point, the 7 interpreter sees that the top of stack contains commands (**`2`** and **`3`**) that aren't representable, so it escapes the top of the stack, producing `723` (which is). The first command output selects the output format; in this case, it's format 7, "format the output the same way as the program". So the commands get output packed into bytes. Then the program continues:

```
23172323
             (implicit) append a copy of the top of stack to the program
        2    Duplicate top of stack (currently 237)
         3   Output top of stack, pop second stack element
          7  Push an empty element onto the stack
```

At this point, there's nothing but empty stack elements on the stack, so the program exits. We output `23` earlier. If we escape **`237`** (and we have to, because it contains unrepresentable commands), we get `7231`. That gets output directly, making the final output of the program `237231` (formatted the same way as the program, i.e. packed into bytes). That's `4fa67f`. (It can be noted that the `1` was entirely pointless in terms of affecting the output; the only reason it's there is to make the two programs different.)

Running `237231` proceeds almost exactly the same way; the difference is that the useless `1` runs just after the first print (and the empty element gets implicitly deleted the second time the current end of the program is reached). Again, the `231` ends up outputting itself, the `23` ends up outputting itself preceded by a `7`, and we get `231723`, the original program.

The observant might note that the two programs, despite being the same length in the language's "native" octal, are different lengths on disk. That's because a 7 program can be padded with an arbitrary number of 1 bits, and the packed format discards the trailing padding. Here's how the encoding happens:

```
2  3  1  7  2  3
010011001111010011(1...)
4   c   f   4   padding
```

In other words, two bytes, `4C` `F4`, are enough to represent the program, so that's all I used.

Answer (score 21):

## Snails, 0 bytes

The second program is

```
1
```

The first program counts the number of matches of the empty pattern on the empty input (which really has area 0, but the pattern is always run at least once as a hack to allow programs to decide what they want to print on empty input). The second program begins with a quantifier (like `{1}` in regex), which causes a parse error. Since the program does not parse successfully, STDOUT is the empty string.

Comment: I thought there was probably a language that did this (i.e. null program succeeds with a nonempty result, but that result does nothing as a program). I tried HOMESPRING but couldn't get the interpreter to work. Looks like you found another language where it works, though. (Do you have a link to an interpreter?)

Comment: @ais523 https://github.com/feresum/PMA or https://tio.run/nexus/snails​.

Answer (score 11):

## Python 3, <s>297</s> <s>279</s> <s>251</s> <s>243</s> <s>225</s> <s>218</s> <s>208</s> <s>180</s> <s>126</s> 111 bytes

Non-cheating:

```
A=''';print(("A="+("'"*3+A)*2).translate({65:66,66:65}))''';print(("A="+("'"*3+A)*2).translate({65:66,66:65}))
```

This prints:

```
B=''';print(("B="+("'"*3+B)*2).translate({65:66,66:65}))''';print(("B="+("'"*3+B)*2).translate({65:66,66:65}))
```

which, when executed, prints the original program.

Comment: Wow! Cool! I never would have thought of that.

Answer (score 8):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 4 Bytes.

[The community seems to consider this sort of thing as a cheating quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78/58375), which thus satisfies the criteria.

```
1
2
```

With a trailing newline.

This prints

```
2
1
```

With a trailing newline, which prints the first code.

RProgN prints the stack popping, so from top to bottom.

[Try it online!](https://tehflamintaco.github.io/Reverse-Programmer-Notation/RProgN.html?rpn=1%0A2%0A&input=)

Comment: There was a chat discussion a while back which implied that `1\n1\n` in RProgN would be a non-cheating quine, because each of the 1s prints each other (and it'd only be considered cheating if each 1 printed itself). All this really implies is that cheating in quines can be hard to define sometimes. (However, this answer is correct either way, because the question doesn't actually *require* the quine to cheat, just *allows* it.)

Comment: Also, Although I was reluctant to say, in RProgN `1\n` is technically a valid quine, as `1` isn't a constant, but a call to a function which pushes `1` to the stack.

Comment: There are multiple definitions of a proper quine in use. That's invalid by at least one, but possibly valid by some of the others.

Comment: @ais523 You've sparked my curiosity, You specified RProgN, yet I didn't think that my little language got that much (or any) attention. Was the chat about RProgN in particular, or a language with a similar syntax?

Comment: It was about [7](http://esolangs.org/wiki/7), which also has a tendency to print segments of the program "backwards". I was extrapolating from the opinions given there.

Answer (score 8):

### Batch, 14 bytes

```
@echo @type %0
```

Which when run as `cyclicquine.bat` outputs

```
@type cyclicquine.bat
```

Which when run outputs the original batch file.

Answer (score 6):

## Jolf, 6 bytes

```
1q_a_q
```

When run, this outputs:

```
q_a_q1
```

Which in turn outputs `1q_a_q`.

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=MXFfYV9x)

## Explanation

```
1q_a_q
1       the digit one (ignored)
 q      the source code (ignored)
     q  the source code
    _   reversed
   a    and outputted
 _      and reversed (ignored)

q_a_q1
q       the source code (ignored)
     1  the digit one (ignored)
    q   the source code
   _    reversed
  a     and outputted
 _      and reversed (ignored)
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>69</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```
(_0=_=>console.log(`(_0=${_0})()`.replace(/0/g,n=>+!+n)))()
```

Outputs:

```
(_1=_=>console.log(`(_1=${_1})()`.replace(/1/g,n=>+!+n)))()
```

---

-1 byte (@ETHProductions): use 0 in regex instead of \d

Comment: Try `n=>1-n` instead of `n=>+!+n`.

Comment: @Conner O'Brien Unfortunately the `1` will end up replaced by the regex.

Comment: @ETHproductions Heh, I should've thought of that.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + Sed, 15 bytes

Same idea as [Dennis's Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102940/48922).

```
sed y/xz/zx/ $0
```

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <s>Cat,</s> and Rev, <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
rev $0 # 0$  ver
```

*-3 thanks to @izabera*

Comment: Wouldn't this be `Bash`, `Tac`, and `Rev?

Comment: `rev $0 # 0$<space><space>ver` for some reason i can't put two spaces in a comment

Comment: Oh, nice @izabera

Comment: @ConorO'Brien No, `tac` `rev`-ed is `cat`.

Comment: @SeeOneRhino Oh.... I see

Answer (score 1):

### ><>, 16 bytes

```
"$r00gol?!;50.01
```

[Try it here!](https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/?script=EQEgTgDBDmD2A2B+AhAbgKwQHQQIxA)

**Outputs**

```
"$r00gol?!;50.10
```

This is a modification of the one provided [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish#Quine). I'm not sure if it's cheating, it reads the codebox and outputs it.

Comment: you can change the 00g to :2- and it'll keep the same byte count without reading the codebox.

Comment: @Tealpelican, thanks! The goal is for it to be considered "cheating" though :p. (And I don't fully understand that rule)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 55 bytes

```c
N,s[];main(){*s^=read(open(__FILE__,0),s,54);puts(s);}
```

Note the trailing newline.

First run:

```c
x,s[];main(){*s^=read(open(__FILE__,0),s,54);puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/99Ppzg61jo3MTNPQ7NaqzjOtig1MUUjvyA1TyM@3s3TxzU@XsdAU6dYx9RE07qgtKRYo1jTupbr/38A)

Second run:

```c
N,s[];main(){*s^=read(open(__FILE__,0),s,54);puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79Cpzg61jo3MTNPQ7NaqzjOtig1MUUjvyA1TyM@3s3TxzU@XsdAU6dYx9RE07qgtKRYo1jTupbr/38A)

This one is rather simple. It reads the file, and XORs the first byte (technically first `int`, but it is effectively the same) with `54`. Since it is an unused variable, it doesn't affect anything.

Note that this abuses the empty array cheat where GCC will let you write up to one page in an array with empty brackets. It also expects the page to be zero filled, which is the default.

A version which does not write out of bounds is this:

```c
y,s[15];main(){*s^=read(open(__FILE__,0),s,56);puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79Spzja0DTWOjcxM09Ds1qrOM62KDUxRSO/IDVPIz7ezdPHNT5ex0BTp1jH1EzTuqC0pFijWNO6luv/fwA)

Which will turn into this

```c
A,s[15];main(){*s^=read(open(__FILE__,0),s,56);puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/99Rpzja0DTWOjcxM09Ds1qrOM62KDUxRSO/IDVPIz7ezdPHNT5ex0BTp1jH1EzTuqC0pFijWNO6luv/fwA)

I xor against `read()` because it returns the number of bytes read, and it is shorter than XORing against a constant.

Answer (score 1):

## [Self-modifying Brainfuck](https://soulsphere.org/hacks/smbf/), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

Note that SMBF stores the program itself to the left of the initial pointer.

```
~<[<]>[-<->]<.>>[.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85NSvv/v84m2ibWLlrXRtcu1kbPzi5azy72/38A)

It will output this (replace `\x82` with a `0x82` byte)

```
\x82<[<]>[-<->]<.>>[.>]
```

Which in turn will print this:

```
~<[<]>[-<->]<.>>[.>]
```

Explanation:

```
~      Dummy byte to be negated to 0x82 (or on second, 0x7e or ~)
<[<]   Scan backwards to the start of the program
>      Go forwards to the first byte
[-<->] Negate cell 0 into cell minus 1
<.     Print the negated byte
>>     Skip to the second byte of the program
[.>]   Print the rest of the program
```

Because I can't directly do it with TIO because it treats inputs as UTF-8, here is a Bash script version which prints outputs with `xxd`:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7UiNVnByE7NkKs4tURBt4yroCgzryRNQanOJtom1i5a10bXLtZGz84uWs8uVknBTqEktbhErzg3KY2roiJFQTfdEEmESz@/oEQfxAQTCBmoPiOoMmSdRri1GiHrNcaiFyL2/z8A)

## [Self-modifying Brainfuck](https://soulsphere.org/hacks/smbf/) (infinite loop, theoretical), 15 bytes

This version is shorter, but instead of exiting normally, it hangs in an infinite loop. Note that you won't see this in the console as the console is line buffered.

```
<[.<]-[][+]<.[<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85NSvv/3yZazyZWNzo2WjvWRi/a5v9/AA)

This will print this:

```
<[.<]+[][-]<.[<
```

which, when run, will print this

```
<[.<]-[][+]<.[<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85NSvv/3yZazyZWOzo2WjfWRi/a5v9/AA)

**Note that in both cases, the code will get stuck in an infinite loop after printing, so you have to manually stop TIO or wait for the timeout**

Explanation:

```
<[.<]    Print the program backwards
-[]      Enter an infinite loop to avoid executing the backwards code
[+]<.[<  The same code backwards (minus the last bracket) which uses a minus
         instead of a plus before the infinite loop.
```

My previous 11 byte infinite loop solution:

```
<[.<]]<.[<+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85NSvv/3yZazyY21kYv2kb7/38A)

I *thought* this was an infinite loop which just sat there spinning, but the instruction pointer will eventually underflow and the program will *very slowly* print endless `0x00` as it tries to traverse a 4 GB loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
`:qpq`:qpq
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%3Aqpq%60%3Aqpq&inputs=&header=&footer=)

This outputs

```
`\`:qpq\`:qpq`
```

Which outputs the original code.

The first is a quine that unevaluates itself, and the second is a string.